# Quick calculator with a single input statement

Tags: python

I am trying to make a quick test calculator that get's all the operation in a single line and a single input statement, but it is giving me a Could not convert string to float error

```
x = input("Calculadora\nEnter the operation: \n")
y = float(x[0])
z = x[1]
w = float(x[2])
print(y + w)
if z == '+':
    s = y + w
    print(s)
```

Comment: what is u desired op ?

Comment: Can you put your input line please?

Comment: I asume you will get this kind of error if you have negative numbers or floats (-1 or 1.05 as numbers)

Comment: You will need to use regex.

Answer (score 1):

For any kind of numbers in your input (negative numbers or floats) you can use:

```
x = input("Calculadora\nEnter the operation: \n")
print(eval(x))
```

If you want to be 100% safety with the user input you can use literal_eval from ast module

```
from ast import literal_eval
print(literal_eval(x))
```

Comment: rusu_ro1 nailed it with this.  He rewrote your app logic in a single line!  Very cool.  Choose this as the correct answer!  It will automagically handle all numbers, operators, parentheses, etc.

Comment: Your script should not have admin rights, and by the way is just a learning example for OS from what I understood

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` method for string.

```
x = input().split('+')
num1 = float(x[0])
num2 = float(x[1])
print(num1 + num2)
```

Of course you can extend this for others operators.

Comment: what about this case "+100 + 100" or "+100 ++ 100" and so on? your code will get  same error as OP mentioned

Comment: So OP can create a new code based in splitting the input as my answer states. IMO it's better than throwing a function that doesn't even was made for that purpose. Yes, it solves OP's problem, but introduces concepts as security hole and performance risks, if you consider he/she's a Python beginner. Besides that, using `eval` doesn't mean a beginner will understand the problem to write a solution, it means Python's parser does.